# AWS SDK/CLI access error with EC2 Instance credentials for aws redshift create-cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I have an IAM role associated with my EC2 instances with the following policy regarding Redshift:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "redshift:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, from my EC2 instance with either the AWS SDK or CLI, I am unable to create a cluster.

Both

```
InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider creds = new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false);
AmazonRedshift redshift = AmazonRedshiftClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(creds).build();

CreateClusterRequest request = new CreateClusterRequest();
request.setAllowVersionUpgrade(true);
request.setClusterType("multi-node");
request.setClusterIdentifier("identifier");
request.setDBName("dbname");
request.setIamRoles(Collections.singleton("iam_role_arn")));
request.setPubliclyAccessible(true);
request.setNodeType("dc1.8xlarge");
request.setNumberOfNodes(2);
request.setPort(8192);
request.setMasterUsername("username");
request.setMasterUserPassword("Password1");
Cluster cluster = redshift.createCluster(request);
```

and

```
aws redshift create-cluster --cluster-identifier identifier --master-username username --master-user-password Password1 --node-type dc1.8xlarge --region us-west-2 --number-of-nodes 2
```

result in:

```
An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the CreateCluster operation: Access Denied. Please ensure that your IAM Permissions allow this operation.
```

Using the IAM policy simulation tool I was able to confirm that my instance role has the permissions to create a Redshift cluster.

Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Check whether you can call `aws redshift describe-clusters`. If that also gives an error, then you are not using credentials associated with the above policy. If the above policy is associated with an IAM Role and the Role is associated with an EC2 instance and you are running the command on the EC2 instance but it is failing, then you probably have alternative credentials stored on the EC2 instance (eg in `.aws/credentials`).

Comment: I can call describe-clusters, and various other commands associated with other policies for the role. I will check for alternative credentials

Comment: It might be that you don't have permission to `PassRole` to Redshift, but that doesn't explain the failure on the command-line where you aren't passing a role.

Comment: Your CLI command worked for me, so it's not a syntax problem nor any missing parameters.

Comment: I fixed the command line issue, it was unrelated. Still having issues with the SDK though. Is PassRole to Redshift a permission outside of "redhsift:*"?

Comment: Yes, it is an IAM setting. See: [Granting a User Permissions to Pass a Role to an AWS Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html) You can test the theory by launching Redshift *without* the role and see if it works.

Comment: You're right, I was able create a cluster if I didn't specify an IAM role. Odd that that isn't mentioned in the documentation for create-cluster (as far as I could tell).
This seems more completed that it's worth, so I'm going to pursue using CloudFormation do this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to call other Redshift operations and it is only failing on `createCluster()`, then the error is probably being caused by **the IAM Role that is being passed to Redshift**.

You need to [Grant a User Permissions to Pass a Role to an AWS Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html).

The logic behind it is this:

- Let's say you do not have access to S3 bucket X
- Let's say there is a role in your account that *does* have access to bucket X
- You could launch a Redshift cluster with the role and then use it to access bucket X
- To prevent people cheating like this, they need `PassRole` permission that states whether they are allowed to pass a role to Redshift and even which roles they are allowed to pass.

The same applies to passing roles to an Amazon EC2 instance.